# angular-ui-bootstrap pagination directive not rendering previous text and next text

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular-ui bootstrap pagination directive and is not rendering previous text and next text buttons.

angular version used: 1.2.28

angular-ui-bootstrap version: 0.12.1

angular module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap.tpls'])
```

html:

```
                       <div pagination
                             total-items="items.total"
                             ng-model="currentPage"
                             items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
                             num-pages="numPages"
                             max-size="5"
                             next-text=">"
                             previous-text="<"
                             >
                        </div>
```

UI is rendered as shown below and is missing prev "<" and next ">" buttons.

[image: bootstrap pagination missing prev-next]

Can anyone help?

Comment: I am stuck with this and really need help. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already tried this but even though it should be 'true' by default you could try adding

```
direction-links="true"
```